# Debug DirectShow by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, windows, directshow, 64-bit, directshow.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and my computer is Win 7 and x64. I successfully built a COM object based on DirectShow, it's a virtual camera and now applications like Skype or YahooMessenger can see my virtual webcam.
What I'm wondering now is debugging the code by Visual Studio 2010. 
Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do. Would you mind talking to me about the implementation? My skype ID is mrpmorris and my email is mrpmorris (@)gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Compile in Debug mode, register your debug build of filter (using regsvr32), go to your project properties -> Debugging and make Command point to the application you want to use your filter in (be it Skype or YM). Then go to Debug -> Start Debugging.

Comment: Thanks Dee Mon, I've tried your instruction but it doesn't work for my application as it's written in C# which isn't supported. I've found in here the tutorial of MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91k1xcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I have done this many times myself (I generally use the "Attach to process" menu option) with C# projects using either native DLLs or managed DLLs. What exactly do you mean with "it is not supported"?